# Adding Datetimes(HH:MM) together to form a (HHHH:MM)?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I'm struggling on datetime calculations - it's one that always gets me! I prefer numbers not time!

So I have various cells with Total hours in each cell. At the end of the row is a Total Hours:Minutes Column that would add these cells together. Each cell's value is a string so needs to be converted first into a DateTime.

My question is how the hell do I do this? Here are a few snippets of what i have so far:

```
string cellvalue = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
Point cursorLocation = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

DataGridView.HitTestInfo hittest = dataGridView1.HitTest(cursorLocation.X, cursorLocation.Y);
DateTime calc = DateTime.Parse((dataGridView1[hittest.ColumnIndex + 1, hittest.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
dataGridView1[dataGridView1.ColumnCount, hittest.RowIndex].Value = ??????
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using TimeSpan. Datetime is storing dates and times, TimeSpan holds time intervals.

Comment: Yes I have had a look at time span but getting the cell value parsed into a timespan? Does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should be using a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, so you'd use

```
TimeSpan calc = TimeSpan.Parse((dataGridView1[hittest.ColumnIndex + 1, hittest.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
```

You can add TimeSpans with `+`.

To format a string to represent totalhours:minutes, you can use

```
String.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes)
```

(assuming the timespan is positive).

Comment: Is there anyway to convert that timespan back into a string of hhhh:mm? The issue I am having now is getting it parse it back I have managed to get hh and hh.mm but then in an if statement it's throws and exception because I am then trying to parse hh.mm back it. All very annoying! I hate working with time :(

Comment: @Chris_livermore I have updated my answer to show a way of getting "hhhh:mm", as you put it.

Comment: thank you very much will input this tomorrow, don't think 8 hours of programming today helped , hopefully I will be a little more awake tomorrow when I digest this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the cells where you have "Total hours", is it a string, a double, a TimeSpan value?

It seems to me you don't need DateTime, just convert all your "TotalHours" to a TimeSpan and add the TimeSpans together, what you show in your Total cell is your TimeSpan TotalHours.

See [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor, TotalHours and Add.